# Facebook Share button parameters don't work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I want to add a facebook share button, but the pop-up doesn't show me the correct parameters. This is my code:

```
<?php

$title=urlencode('Title of the iFrame Tab');
$url=urlencode('http://my-domain/index.php?langue=eng&table_pub=publication_eng&id=22&rub=publication');
$summary=urlencode('Custom message here');
$image=urlencode('http://my-domain/img.png');
?>
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Share</a>
```

But this code always show me a pop-up like this:
[image]

Comment: I followed this article, it helped me to find the suitable solution:
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-add-facebook-share-button-to-your-web-site-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no longer supports custom parameters in sharer.php.

[Official facebook answer](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/)

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook javascropt sdk ,

[check this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

your share button  ,

```
  <a href="yoururl" data-image="yourimage" data-title="title" data-desc="Some description" class="fbshare">FBShare</a>
```

On button click,

```
   $('.fbshare').click(function(){
   elem = $(this);
   postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'),
    elem.prop('href'), 
   elem.data('image'));

   return false;
    });
```

Comment: tried that but didn't work. Clicking on link just opens the href url. No facebook interaction